# Navigating Bootstrap Tabs via PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using Bootstrap 'Tab' on a project and trying to set each tabs `<li class ="active"></li>` dynamically via PHP. I've been successful in making the class 'active' and displaying the specific tab that I want visible.

However the issue is, even though the tab and the corresponding tab panel displays correctly on screen, the content inside the tab panel disappears. If I manually go back and forth and try to navigate the tabs I still can see the content is still there.

What am I missing here?

**Here is the code snippet for a tab:**

```
    <li role="presentation" class="<? if(!empty($status2)) echo $status2; ?>">
        <a href="#tab2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <div class="cont2">
            <? if(!empty($block2)) echo $block2; ?>
        </div>
        </a>
     </li>
```

**and the corresponding code for the tab panel:**

```
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane if(!empty($status2)) echo $status2; ?>" id="tab2">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="txt2" name="txt2" placeholder="Sample text in Page 2">
            <input type="submit" id="send2" name="send2" value="ClickMe">
        </form> 
       </div>
```

Comment: Confused a little bit. Are you talking this one?: `<? if(!empty($block2)) echo $block2; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have mistake in this line:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane if(!empty($status2)) echo $status2; ?>" id="tab2">
```

at first render panel doesn't appear because it hasn't appropriate class. When you click on tabs, the class set becomes right.

fix the mistake and it should go well.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php if(!empty($status2)) echo $status2; ?>" id="tab2">
```